# How to reload window in Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working n Firefox add-on & I have implemented `login & log-out` functionality. I am facing issue while `reloading the window after the Log-in & Log-out.`  I have tried to reload the tab using the `tab-SDK API` but it doesn't fulfill my requirement , also I have tried using `window.reload` at content scripts but it reloads the panel for me not the window.

Can you help to resolve the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want tab.reload():

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#reload%28%29